# writing AVI frame grabber with DirectShow with c++ on WinCE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, directshow

I want to write a simple frame grabber to get the frames 1 by 1 from an AVI video with directshow.

I use VS2005 to write programs for wince 6. the problem is, I don't know anything about directshow, I need a good and simple starting point to read about it.

and also,I want to get FrameRate, Width and Height of video, BitRate, and the length of video, can I do it with directShow too?

Arta

Comment: This is way too broad for us to hand hold you, I suggest you download the sdk, look at the [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or find some tutorials online or an out of print [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Microsoft%C2%AE-DirectShow%C2%AE-Television-Pro-Developer/dp/0735618216/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1389084807&sr=8-1&keywords=directshow), to answer your last point yes you can get all that info but it depends on the source type, most video files will have metadata with all that info but it is sometimes unreliable, good luck

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use a SampleGrabber Filter. It is called deprecated, but still available in windows 8. The source might also been included in the directx 9 sdk but not in newer versions. But I don't know if that can be used on wince too. The following page seems to indicate it is not, and offers a different implementation: 
[Creating Custom DirectShow SampleGrabber Filter for Windows Mobile](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28790/Creating-Custom-DirectShow-SampleGrabber-Filter-fo)

Also useful is this tutorial written by Roman: [How To: Dump DirectShow media samples](http://alax.info/blog/574)